# Possible pass-by-reference issue but I'm not sure, but one useless line of code changes end-result drastically?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, pass-by-reference

I'm making a chess game in C++ and I have come in to a bit of an issue. I'm not sure if it is related to memory or pass-by-reference or what, but this is part of my code:

```
else if (aPiece[aGame.MainGrid[0][x][y]][aGame.MainGrid[1][x][y]].Status == 4)  //Rook
{
    int r = -1;

    //ROOK FUNCTION
    for (int s = x - 1; s >= 0; s--)
    {
        r = aGame.PieceMoveLookFunction(aGame, s, y, aOpponentValue);

        if (r > 0)  //Possible piece movement
        {
            //Next move for piece
            c = s;
            d = y;
            //Current location of piece
            g = x;
            h = y;

            aGame.AlterSavedGrid(aGame, aPiece, c, d, g, h);
            if (aGame.NotViolateCheckFunction(aGame, aPiece)) { aGame.PredictGrid[c][d] = aGame.PredictCount; } //Possible Move
            aGame.RestoreSavedGrid(aGame, aPiece);  //Restore MainGrid with SavedGrid after checking next move
```

With the above code included, here is the result:
[won't let me post images, I'm new on here]

Basically it is a White Rook on the far right, H3 with no White or Black pieces to its left. It only says I can move one space to the left, G3 instead of all the way to the left.

Now with only adding one line of unnecessary and unused code such as this:

```
else if (aPiece[aGame.MainGrid[0][x][y]][aGame.MainGrid[1][x][y]].Status == 4)  //Rook
{
    int r = -1;
    string ATEMP;  <<< This Line Only!!         
    //ROOK FUNCTION
```

It changes to this:
[again, no picture]

Now I can move my White Rook, H3 all the way to the left square, A3 and anywhere in between. It isn't this section of code that causes the problem because the Queen uses the exact same code and works. Also, when the Rook can, it has no problem moving up, right, or down all the way.

The rook should be doing what the second picture is doing: the yellow represents all possible moves. I haven't used C++ in several years, and even that was elementary but I started using "&" symbols in my function parameters recently. Could this attribute to the problem or any other theories? Just to be clear, "string ATEMP" does nothing and is used by nothing. Thank you.

Comment: If just adding a redundant variable has such a drastic change, I would *guess* that you have an array overrun or underrun somewhere and the new variable is masking that by introducing a different layout of data internally.

Comment: Yup, there's probably undefined behaviour afoot.

Comment: I also just switched from Debug mode to Release mode and the problem isn't there anymore. But going back to Debug still shows issues.

Comment: Run it through a debugger.

Comment: I ran a code analysis and it gave me a warning C6385: accessing <some array>, the readable size is '256' bytes, but <some number> might be read. Lines <etc etc>. But the code lines are not even in this part of the code. They are in the draw method, opposed to the update method.

Comment: So your draw method has undefined behaviour, which has effects somewhere else. This kind of misleading failure is quite common when you have UB.

Comment: Alright figured it out, well at least I think its fixed. I was passing-by-reference local variables that would go out of scope. I fixed that issue, but running code analysis will still show warnings so I don't know for sure what's up with that. Thank you for the help all.